# Efficient method to convert set of ranges in a dataframe to frequency of individual elements?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working in R. I have a data-frame which contains the start and end positions on a chromosome (where integer represents a coordinate on the chromosome) Ex:

```
start     end
1         5
3         7
4         10
12        7            (inverted is also allowed)
8         15
```

What I want is to count how many times a coordinate is present in all these ranges. So, for the above example, the output would be this:

```
position     count
1            1
2            1
3            2
4            3
5            3
6            2
7            3
8            3
9            3
10           3
11           2
12           2
13           1
14           1
15           1
```

I have 62000+ such ranges, where each range is at least 1000 positions long. I know how to do this conversion but I don't know how to do this efficiently, that is with in couple of seconds.

Current (inefficient code)

```
positions <- c()
for(i in seq(nrow(a))){
  positions <- c(positions, seq(a[i,3], a[i,4]))
}
table(positions)
```

"a" is my data-frame and the start and end coordinates are in the third and forth column respectively.

One of the columns in the data-frame contains characters, so for using `apply` I would either need to create a new data-frame (consuming extra space) or would need to convert to integers inside the apply function (extra time). Sorry, for not informing about this earlier.

Comment: You might, also, give "IRanges" a try -- `r = seq_len(do.call(max, a)); cbind(r, countOverlaps(IRanges(r, r), IRanges(do.call(pmin, a), do.call(pmax, a))))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a very fast code with `data.table` see the answer from *docendo discimus*
(+ benchmark)

Here is the benchmark of some other solutions:

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 1000
df <- data.frame(start=sample.int(10*N, N))
df$end <- df$start + sample(3:20, N, rep=TRUE) 

library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(unit = "relative",
ori =  { positions <- c()
  for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
    positions <- c(positions, seq(df[i,1], df[i,2]))
  }
  table(positions) },
a  = table(unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2]))),  # my solution, similar: KenS, EricSchutte
m1 = table(unlist(mapply(seq, df$start, df$end))),        # my variant of Sotos' solution
m2 = table(unlist(mapply(':', df$start, df$end))),        # my variant of Sotos' solution
M1 = table(unlist(Map(seq, df$start, df$end))),           # my variant of Sotos' solution
M2 = table(unlist(Map(':', df$start, df$end))),           # Sotos
l  = table(unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) seq(df$start[i], df$end[i])))),    # lmo
t  = { temp <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) seq(df$start[i], df$end[i])))  # lmo tabulate()
cbind(sort(unique(temp)), tabulate(temp)) },
d  = table(do.call(c, mapply(seq, df$start, df$end))),     # @989 (comment to the answer from Sotos)
dd = table(do.call(c, mapply(seq.int, df$start, df$end))), # docendo discimus (comment to this answer)
f  = {  pos <- data.frame(x=(min(df):max(df)),n=0)         # Andrew Gustar

for(i in seq_along(df$start)){
  low=min(df$start[i])-pos$x[1]+1
  high=max(df$end[i])-pos$x[1]+1
  pos$n[low:high] <- pos$n[low:high]+1
} }
)
# Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval    cld
#  ori 7.163767 7.219099 7.573688 7.379160 7.912435  7.899586   100     e 
#    a 1.194627 1.194855 1.211432 1.209485 1.213118  1.711994   100 a     
#   m1 1.645659 1.660294 1.711141 1.686973 1.710461  2.217141   100  b    
#   m2 1.005302 1.007125 1.017115 1.009618 1.017207  1.576201   100 a     
#   M1 1.642688 1.645174 1.733173 1.673924 1.686253  2.218028   100  b    
#   M2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000   100 a     
#    l 3.487924 3.512732 3.801530 3.665725 4.188701  4.216375   100    d  
#    t 2.670636 2.711345 2.961449 2.869190 3.066150  3.745984   100   c   
#    d 1.652376 1.650798 1.721377 1.665901 1.712064  2.187129   100  b    
#   dd 1.040941 1.045652 1.060601 1.047534 1.053305  1.592163   100 a     
#    f 8.287098 8.486854 9.052884 9.046376 9.126318 25.210722   100      f
```

The solution with `tabulate()` produces warnings.

Answer (score 7):

One idea,

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(Map(`:`, df$start, df$end))))

#   Var1 Freq
#1     1    1
#2     2    1
#3     3    2
#4     4    3
#5     5    3
#6     6    2
#7     7    3
#8     8    3
#9     9    3
#10   10    3
#11   11    2
#12   12    2
#13   13    1
#14   14    1
#15   15    1
```

Comment: Or `data.frame(table(do.call(c, mapply(seq, df$start, df$end))))`

Comment: @989 True, but it's much more readable with `unlist` (rather than `do.call(c, ...)`). (Not sure about efficiency)

Answer (score 4):

This is roughly the same algorithm you are using, but should be faster.

```
myNums <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) seq(df$start[i], df$end[i])))

table(myNums)
myNums
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 1  1  2  3  3  2  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  1  1
```

An even faster method would be to use `tabulate` rather than `table`.  For example,

```
temp <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) seq(df$start[i], df$end[i])))
cbind(sort(unique(temp)), tabulate(temp))
```

which returns the matrix

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    1
 [3,]    3    2
 [4,]    4    3
 [5,]    5    3
 [6,]    6    2
 [7,]    7    3
 [8,]    8    3
 [9,]    9    3
[10,]   10    3
[11,]   11    2
[12,]   12    2
[13,]   13    1
[14,]   14    1
[15,]   15    1
```

runs about 50% faster for the given data set.

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
    table 223.233 237.6305 250.0329 245.8985 253.4545 423.944   100   b
 tabulate 142.835 159.0860 166.9775 167.3540 175.7650 195.009   100  a
```

Comment: yups. 'lapply' is faster indeed, 'table' is still slow though. but I guess I can be happy with it. many thanks.

Comment: I found an even faster method that uses `tabulate` instead of `table`. It is the no frills workhorse for `table`.

Comment: Tabulate would give 0 for integers which are not present, so it is not useful. ex: for temp <- c(1,2,4,5);

Comment: In that instance, you could add a line to separately tabulate and then drops 0s in the `cbind`: `tab <- tabulate(temp); cbind(sort(unique(temp)), tab[tab > 0])`.

Answer (score 4):

I'll propose a data.table solution since we're interested in performance. The approach looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, list(seq.int(start, end)), by = 1:nrow(df)][, .N, by = V1]
```

And it performs very well compared to the other solutions despite by-row operation.

Here's a benchmark on **1e4** rows:

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 1e4
vals = 1:100
df <- data.frame(start=sample(vals, N, replace = TRUE), end = sample(vals, N, replace = TRUE))
library(data.table)
library("microbenchmark")
dt <- copy(df)
setDT(dt)

microbenchmark(unit = "relative", times = 10,
               jogo = table(unlist(Map(seq, df$start, df$end))),           # jogo
               sotos = table(unlist(Map(':', df$start, df$end))),           # Sotos
               lmo  = table(unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) seq(df$start[i], df$end[i])))),    # lmo
               orig_989  = table(do.call(c, mapply(seq, df$start, df$end))),     # @989 (comment to the answer from Sotos)
               mod_989  = table(do.call(c, mapply(seq.int, df$start, df$end))), # docendo discimus (comment to this answer)
               dd = dt[, list(seq.int(start, end)), by = 1:nrow(dt)][, .N, by = V1]
)

Unit: relative
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
     jogo  8.794179  8.735461 19.226146  8.584978  8.637774 52.782168    10  ab
    sotos 10.669810 10.623685  8.984351 10.437937 10.164045  4.846189    10  ab
      lmo 21.319154 21.117393 27.452902 22.558436 22.913901 43.403024    10   b
 orig_989  9.190209  8.725191  7.532509  8.730023  8.516305  3.948500    10  ab
  mod_989  5.372087  5.097636  5.067462  5.305532  6.214493  3.188091    10  ab
       dd  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10  a
```

Comment: chapeau, very nice! My really own solution was `table(unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])))`

Answer (score 2):

I create a sequence for every line in `df`, e.g. `c(1,2,3,4,5)` for the first line. by using:

```
all.pos <- apply(df, 1, function(x){x[1]:x[2]})
all.pos <- unlist(all.pos)
#  1  2  3  4  5  3  4  5  6  7  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 11 10  9  8  7  8  9 
#  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Table will count how often every position occurs in `all.pos`.

```
table(all.pos)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
# 1  1  2  3  3  2  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: short: `table(unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[1]:x[2])))`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, avoiding `table`, looping through the ranges and adding 1 to the relevant values each time...

```
ranges <- data.frame(start=c(1,3,4,12,8), end=c(5,7,10,7,15) )

pos <- data.frame(x=(min(ranges):max(ranges)),n=0)

for(i in seq_along(ranges$start)){
  low=min(ranges$start[i])-pos$x[1]+1
  high=max(ranges$end[i])-pos$x[1]+1
  pos$n[low:high] <- pos$n[low:high]+1
}

pos
    x n
1   1 1
2   2 1
3   3 2
4   4 3
5   5 3
6   6 2
7   7 3
8   8 3
9   9 3
10 10 3
11 11 2
12 12 2
13 13 1
14 14 1
15 15 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that came up, might not be the best but by using apply things should significantly go faster.

```
df <- data.frame(start=c(1,3,4,12,8), end=c(5,7,10,7,15) )

positions <- apply(df, 1, function (x) {
  seq(x[1], x[2])
})

table(unlist(positions))
```

yields..

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 1  1  2  3  3  2  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  1  1
```